# Take into consideration that user add element by themselves onto HTML when coding JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I was doing my school work and I noticed that I can add an element to the HTML through the developer console. I created a JS function and it uses a querySelector to select 6 divs from my webpage. However, if a user manually adds or removes a div using the developer console, my function doesn't work anymore.

Do I have to take into consideration that users can mess with the HTML when I write my JS functions?

Sorry if it seems like a silly question. I'm new to HTML, CSS and JS.

Comment: @CertainPerformance That sounds more like an answer than a comment ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, don't bother. If someone's going to try to change your HTML in a way not done through standard interaction with the site, the onus is on *them* to do it in such a way that the website's functionality remains intact, if that's something they want to preserve. It would also be literally impossible to account for every possible custom DOM modification that might be done.

Answer (score 0):

Changes made onto the developers console does not affect your actual website, because it's all down on their specific browser. The changes aren't communicated back to the actual server hosting & serving the html files.

You can 100% ignore people changing your site via their developers console.